# Decimal number changed to whole number

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, qgis-2.18

I am working in QGIS 2.18.0 version.

My analysis involves using vector filed calculator for some operation. This new filed I am creating with an output filed type as Decimal number(integer). I wrote expression and it works fine but when I save it the field type changes to Whole number.

[image: Screen shot of attribute table]

In above image **SlopeRati** was Decimal type and I created one more filed **SlopeRati1** and stored orginal decimal values as STRING. After saving this later doest not change but earlier filed becomes Whole number.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @PulkitVelani! When you use decimal numbers, you can specify the **precision** of how many positions after the decimal point you want to include in your field. So just make sure it's not `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Decimal number(integer)

Is a whole number.

You want to use:

`Decimal number (real)`

Also as mentioned by Joseph in the comments make sure you have a precision set. So **precision** is how many decimal places get saves and **width** is the overall number if digits stored both before and after the decimal place.